how to autoclean or fix the broken/ legacy package/cli in /opt/homebrew/bin
so after upgrade python with homebrew, I found that ipython and pip cli in /opt/homebrew/bin are broken.
how to fix: auto cleanup all broken cli/packages?
~
❯ which -a pip pip3
pip: aliased to pip3
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
❯/opt/homebrew/bin/pip --version
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11: no such file or directory

